# mac + linux execute jar file?

Tags: linux, macos, shell, sh

Will this work on both linux + mac? I don't have a test computer but from your experiences will this do?

Run jar(mac&linux).sh

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar client.jar $*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

​Y​o​u want `"$@"`, not `$*`.​ And don't forget to make the script itself executable.

Comment: what does "$@" mean? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: `"$@"` will send each individual argument to the script as individual arguments to `java`. `$*` will bunch them up, split on whitespace, and send each individual word as individual arguments. This matters when arguments to the script contain whitespace.

Comment: @Kyle: Possibly off topic, but [alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) is not a word.

Comment: @Kyle To answer the question: It will work for any OS that has a POSIX compliant shell. According to Wikipedia, Mac OS-X has a POSIX compliant shell.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create manifest file (make sure you have the jar files in the location your specifying too) and then you can run: java -jar [your_full_path}/[you_jar_file_name].jar